# Mongo DB - How to get only the inserted Object in an array when calling collection.watch()

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am having a little problem with my code.

I have a collection called `user_relations` and there I save friends that a specific user has.

One document example:
[image]

So my question is: How can I only get the Object item that has been added to `arrayOfFriends` without getting all of the other values inside that array and outside. For example:
If I insert `{"userId" : "2", "lastMessage" : "Hello"}` into `arrayOfFriends`, I want that my response looks like this: `{"userId" : "2", "lastMessage" : "Hello"}` and not like this `{"_id" : ObjectId("id..."), "arrayOfFriends" : {...}}`.

The code that I am currently using:

```
    var stream = db.collection('user_relations').watch(<Map<String, Object>>[
      {
        '$match': {
          '$and': [
            {'operationType': 'insert'},
            {'fullDocument.userId': '6fcfd7b3847dd9999430f1ad'}
          ]
        }
      }
    ]);

    stream.listen((changeEvent) {
      Map fullDocument = changeEvent.fullDocument;
      print('fullDocument: $fullDocument');
      // Insert your logic here
    });
```

The code is written in flutter, but I think it is pretty similar to Node.js and Python and can be read easily.

Thank You!

Comment: You tagged mongoose, but say this is Flutter.  Is there any auto-mapping via mongoose in your application?

Comment: I believe you are attempting to use the MongoDB Change Streams functionality https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/usage-examples/changeStream/.  There is an option to include the full document, but in either case the strategy is simple: when a change to a record occurs, provide the application with the ID of the record.  With the option `fullDocument:true`, the change stream will re-query for the document based on the id and include it in the payload.  If you only want part of the payload you have 2 options.  Either re-query yourself with a projection or use part of the returned payload.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the OP was asking about how to create this using Flutter.  Nonetheless here is a node example not using mongoose, but only using the raw driver...

```
npm init -y
npm install mongodb
```

**Create file app.js**

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');


const uri = "mongodb://barry:barry@localhost:50011,localhost:50012,localhost:50013/nodetest?replicaSet=replSet&authSource=admin";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
const collectionName = "user_relations";


client.connect(function(err) {
    const db = client.db("nodetest");
    const collection = db.collection(collectionName);
    
    const pipeline = [
      {
        "$match": {
            "operationType": "insert",
            "fullDocument.userId": "6fcfd7b3847dd9999430f1ad"
        }
      }
    ];
    
    const stream = collection.watch(pipeline);
    const changeStreamOptions = { fullDocument: "updateLookup" };
    stream.on("change", stream_OnChange, changeStreamOptions);

});

function stream_OnChange(documentChange) {
    console.log(documentChange.fullDocument.arrayOfFriends);
}
```

Probably need to change the connection string, and/or database names.

**Execute using nodemon...**

```
nodemon app.js
```

**Insert into the MongoDB database using mongoshell...**

```
db.user_relations.insert({userId: "6fcfd7b3847dd9999430f1ad", arrayOfFriends: [ {userId: 1, lastMessage: "Message 1"}, {userId: 1, lastMessage: "Message 2"}] })
```

**See output in nodemon window**

```
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
[
  { userId: 1, lastMessage: 'Message 1' },
  { userId: 1, lastMessage: 'Message 2' }
]
```

**Conclusion and Evaluation**

Notice the output is only part of the full document?  This is because the stream_OnChange method is referring to the sub fields directly.  Is this what you are after?

**EDIT 2021-08-29**

Per comments by the OP, the desire is to see an item that is added to an array, presumably by a $push operation, but show only that item.  The strategy for this is to NOT look at the object "fullDocument" but instead look at the operation in the changestream.

To illustrate this, I have modified the function `stream_OnChange(documentChange)` as described above in the file `app.js`.

```
function stream_OnChange(documentChange) {
    console.log("##### FULL PAYLOAD #####");
    console.log(documentChange);
    console.log("##### END FULL PAYLOAD #####");
    
    try {
        var updatedFields = documentChange.updateDescription.updatedFields;
        
        Object.keys(updatedFields).forEach( function (key1, index1, _array1) {
            var value1 = updatedFields[key1];
            console.log(key1 + ": " + value1);

            Object.keys(value1).forEach( function (key2, index2, _array2) {
                var value2 = value1[key2];

                console.log(key2 + ":" + value2);
            });

        });
    }
    catch(e) {
    
    }
}
```

Here, I am parsing the response of the update peeling apart the updateDescription and looking specifically at the updatedFields.

For example, lets say I push a new object to my array...

```
db.user_relations.updateOne({ userId: "6fcfd7b3847dd9999430f1ad" }, { $push: { arrayOfFriends: { userId: 1, lastMessage: "Message 3" } } }
```

)

**Example of output:**

```
##### FULL PAYLOAD #####
{
  _id: {
    _data: '82612BD118000000012B022C0100296E5A10041B035F339E2B48B6A3A5E707D801316A46645F69640064612BD10D69B433970757F4EF0004'
  },
  operationType: 'update',
  clusterTime: new Timestamp({ t: 1630261528, i: 1 }),
  ns: { db: 'nodetest', coll: 'user_relations' },
  documentKey: { _id: new ObjectId("612bd10d69b433970757f4ef") },
  updateDescription: {
    updatedFields: { 'arrayOfFriends.2': [Object] },
    removedFields: [],
    truncatedArrays: []
  }
}
##### END FULL PAYLOAD #####
arrayOfFriends.2: [object Object]
userId:1
lastMessage:Message 3
```

To catch updates I needed to modify app.js client connect method - specifically the pipeline definition...

```
client.connect(function(err) {
    const db = client.db("nodetest");
    const collection = db.collection(collectionName);
    
    const pipeline = [
      {
        "$match": {
            "operationType": "update"
        }
      }
    ];
    
    
    const stream = collection.watch(pipeline);
    const changeStreamOptions = { fullDocument: "updateLookup" };
    stream.on("change", stream_OnChange, changeStreamOptions);
});
```

Comment: Hey Barry, I really appreciate the time that you put in by writing this, but really my question is: How can I only get the Object that has been added to the array. I can do this like you wrote up there but I will get too much data. When an Object is added, I only need that object, not the full array. Is there any way that I can achieve this? Thank You

Comment: I have tried this approach and it still won't give me the result that I want. Thank You

Comment: Hi @BilalDrndo - Your original post shows you are performing a filtered watch on the collection.  That is to say, you only want watch for inserts, and not watch for updates.  If that is the case, then all the data in the field fullDocument will be what was recently added.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Hi @BilalDrndo - If you are interested in seeing updates, not inserts, then see edit comments in my post - "Edit 2021-08-29"